# How do I check out a specific version of a submodule using 'git submodule'?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

How would I go about adding a Git submodule for a specific tag or commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule)

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Submodule repositories stay in a detached HEAD state pointing to a specific commit. Changing that commit simply involves checking out a different tag or commit then adding the change to the parent repository.

```
$ cd submodule
$ git checkout v2.0
Previous HEAD position was 5c1277e... bumped version to 2.0.5
HEAD is now at f0a0036... version 2.0
```

`git-status` on the parent repository will now report a dirty tree:

```
# On branch dev [...]
#
#   modified:   submodule (new commits)
```

Add the submodule directory and commit to store the new pointer.

Comment: After I commited the parent repo with a specific branch/version of a submodule, can others checkout the same version of submodule in the future? Or, they have to specified manually again?

Comment: @QZHua: I experimented with this myself and it seems that the commit ID of the submodule is preserved when the parent is cloned.

Comment: and here we go into the dark zone..... i can commit to my local git,.... but maybe not push to origin.... which could render  this unsharable.....
experience tells..... beware!
if the submodule changes a lot it will cause trouble

Answer (score 58):

> Step 1: Add the submodule
>
> ```
>    git submodule add git://some_repository.git some_repository
> ```
>
> Step 2: Fix the submodule to a particular commit
>
> By default the new submodule will be tracking HEAD of the master branch, but it will NOT be updated as you update your primary repository. In order to change the submodule to track a particular commit or different branch, change directory to the submodule folder and switch branches just like you would in a normal repository.
>
> ```
>    git checkout -b some_branch origin/some_branch
> ```
>
> Now the submodule is fixed on the development branch instead of HEAD of master.

*From [Two Guys Arguing — Tie Git Submodules to a Particular Commit or Branch](https://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/tie-git-submodules-to-a-particular-commit-or-branch/) .*

Comment: It's easier to use `git submodule add -b some_branch git://some_repository.git some_repository`

Comment: At this moment it doesn't seem that `git submodule add -b` can take a tag or a sha1hash. It can only take a branch.

Comment: Is there an issue for this in the Git issue tracker? Would someone kindly post a URL so we can track it?  Thanks.

Comment: @colan instructions for reporting bugs are at https://git-scm.com/community. But `-b`'s supporting branches and not tags or commit shas is a feature not a bug (in fact `-b` is shorthand for `--branch`).

Comment: Sigh.  After all these years, they still don't have a public issue tracker.

Comment: There's no github for git, but you can just search the archives: https://public-inbox.org/git/?q=submodule+add+tag