# Installing python package from git at tag with setup.py

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a package (foo) in a private git repo. I want to install foo for use by another package, bar, via bar's setup.py. I want a specific version - the versioning in setup.py for foo matches its git tags (0.3.2, the git tag is v0.3.2)

The setup.py for bar looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
  
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='bar',
        install_requires=['foo@ git+ssh://git@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git@v0.3.2#subdirectory=somedir']
    )
```

I have also tried added the version explicitly at the end:

```
install_requires=['foo@ git+ssh://git@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git@v0.3.2#subdirectory=somedir==0.3.2']
```

I currently have version 0.3.1 installed in my venv.
When I try to install this setup.py, via `pip install .`, or `pip install . -U` the version isn't upgraded - the repo isn't even checked out:

```
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: foo@ git+ssh://git@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git@v0.3.2#subdirectory=src==0.3.2 from 
git+ssh://****@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git@v0.3.2#subdirectory=src==0.3.2 in 
./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bar==0.0.0) (0.3.1)
```

However, when I use pip to install foo directly, the upgrade is done:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git@v0.3.2#subdirectory=src

Collecting git+ssh://****@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git@v0.3.2#subdirectory=src
  Cloning ssh://****@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git (to revision v0.3.2) to /tmp/pip-req-build-gxj2duq6
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-gxj2duq6
  Running command git checkout -q 40fa65eb75fc26541c90ee9e489ae6dd5538db1f
  Running command git submodule update --init --recursive -q
...
Installing collected packages: foo
  Attempting uninstall: foo
    Found existing installation: foo0.3.1
    Uninstalling foo-0.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled foo-0.3.1
    Running setup.py install for foo... done
Successfully installed foo-0.3.2
```

I can't understand why installing with setup.py gives different behaviour. How do I ensure that it checks out the repo and looks for the correct version?

Follow up question - how would I specify 'check master branch for foo and install whatever version is there if it is higher than the current installed version'?

Comment: Have you tried the form proposed by [Dock Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794506/2272172)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a precise and valid question, but I'm not confident that a satisfying answer will come. I'm not sure why what you're doing isn't working, but using direct URL dependencies with pip and setuptools is a new and rather complicated feature, and is possibly buggy/lacking on setuptools' side.

What I assume you want to do is have the package `foo` as a dependencies of `bar` - you don't actually need to use the [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) direct URL specifier format. Instead you can provide either `pip` or `setuptools` with (relative) paths as dependency specifiers, and then use Git submodules to populate those paths. For example:

```sh
git submodule add git@github.com/fergusmac/foo.git
pip install ./foo
```

This will install whatever revision of foo was checked out when you added the submodule. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916398/5946921) explains, you can change the checked-out revision of the submodule and then install it like so:

```sh
cd foo
git checkout v0.3.2
cd ..
pip install ./foo
```

For setuptools you can specify it like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

...

setup(
    name='bar',
    install_requires=[
        f'foo @ file://localhost/{Path(__file__).parent}/foo/',
    ],
)
```

`Path(__file__).parent` is the directory containing bar's `setup.py` file. The path that follows that bit (e.g. `/foo/` in this case) should be the location of foo's submodule relative to the directory containing bar's `setup.py` file.

---

> Follow up question - how would I specify 'check master branch for foo and install whatever version is there if it is higher than the current installed version'?

Checkout `master` in the submodule, then install via `pip install --upgrade .` (assuming `.` is the project directory for bar).

---

See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365583/271937